# Why did this way to save an array of normalized pixels in PNG file not work?

Tags: python, arrays, image, save, png

I searched many questions about saving an array of pixels in PNG file and made some modifications based on the previous answers. But my code still does not work. The system keeps printing out "cannot convert". Could anybody give any advice? I will greatly appreciate it.

```
for i in range(0, len(imgfile)-1):
    img = cv2.imread(join(mypath,imgfile[i]),cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    imgs[i] = cv2.normalize(img, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, 
dtype=cv2.CV_32F)

height=100
width=100
max_pat=1000
total_size=len(imgs)*max_pat*height*width*3
patches = np.zeros(total_size)
patches = patches.reshape(len(imgs), max_pat, height, width, 3)
patches = patches.astype('float32')

# Create patches and save to PNG files
for i in range(0, len(imgs)-1):
    arr = np.array(imgs[i])
    patches[i,:,:,:,:] = extract_patches_2d(arr, (height, width), max_pat)
    for j in range(0, max_pat-1):
        try:
           image.fromarray(patches[i,j,:,:,:],'RGB').save(join(pathto,'pic',str(i),str(j),'.PNG'),'PNG')
        except IOError:
            print "cannot convert"
```

Comment: It would help to see the traceback (or at least print the exception).

Comment: What's the image's dtype when you call fromarray? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html Can't you just use imwrite in cv2? It would be helpful to have running code...

Comment: It worked after I concatenated the path name and the file name by "+" instead of join(). Thanks for the comments.